# EJS variable not define in html

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, ejs

I'm trying to read a JSON file from my database. Here is the rendered page.

```
    <% newcompose.forEach(function(post){ %>

        <h1><%= post.caption %></h1>
        <p><%= post.text %></p>

    <% }); %>
```

And this is how i'm passing the value into `newcompose`.

```
Post.find({}, function(err, posts){
    if(!err){
        res.render("home", {newcompose: posts});
    }
});
```

It says newcompose not defined but if I add `<% var newcompose; %>` to home then it says forEach not defined. also I'm using mongoose.

Comment: have you determined that `posts` has a value

Answer (score 1):

I tested your template using the following code:

```
const ejs = require('ejs');

let template = `
<%newcompose.forEach(function(post){%>
    <h1><%=post.caption%></h1>
    <p><%=post.text%></p>
<%});%>
`;

const renderData = {
    newcompose: [
        {
            caption: "test caption",
            text: "test text",
        }
    ]
};
const output = ejs.render(template, renderData);

console.log(output);
```

output was:

```
    <h1>test caption</h1>
    <p>test text</p>
```

So your template is fine. This implies that the problem is with your `find` function, or how you are handling the callback parameters.

If you are using mongo, this is likely because find returns a cursor, so you need to explicitly call the toArray function like this:

```
collection.find().toArray(function(err, documents) {
```

As per: https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursor.html

Comment: @Maurice - Ok, if my answer was helpful I would appreciate it if you could 'accept' it. Thanks.